# AngularJS : What to unit test and what to not

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, global, local

```
function post(url, data, headers) {
        var config =
        {
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            postData: data,
            headers: headers
        };
        return httpHandler(config);
    }
```

Above is my piece of code that I want to unit test. Now my confusion is whether I should unit test httpHandler function seperatly or I should not bother about what it is going to return.

If it is possible to test it separately, then what can be my possible test cases and if not then what will be test cases.
I am very new to unit test hence Any help is Appreciated !!!
Thanks

Comment: if you use `$httpBackend` to mock `$http`, then this is a **unit test**, because this *unit* of code can be tested in isolation.  If, instead, you test this against a server of some sort, this becomes an **integration test**.  The types of tests and the results you test for will be different depending on this.

Comment: Forget about $httpBackend, consider only the above line of codes , inside one function I have return httphandler().

Comment: What does the `httpHandler` function do, exactly? That's not a built in angular function;  presumably, a unit test of this `post` function is really checking to see if you receive the correct `httpHandler` object, which *technically* is making this a test of the `httpHandler` function return.

Comment: essentially, this `post` function is not a unit of it's own, since it is tightly coupled to the result of the `httpHandler` function.

Comment: If you're just testing `post` and `httpHandler` is injectable, you would simply mock `httpHandler` as it is a [collaborator](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html#CollaboratorIsolation) and verify that it was called with an object corresponding to the args passed to `post` with the inclusion of `method: 'POST'`.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your valuable comments